# How to disable bcdedit debug off?

Tags: windows, windbg

I tried to do bcdedit debug on. Later I reboot pc but hanging at boot time. I tried several option from internet not useful. I tried to disable bcdedit at command prompt from advanced option, but bcdedit is not recognised,

Comment: So you don't want to disable the command `bcddebug off` but you rather want to turn the debug mode off, is that right?

Comment: Actually in boot time command prompt from recovery options bcdedit is not recognised. Saying boot configuration is not present for this process. So I am not able to disable bcdedit debug to off, since it's hanging during boot time. Before reboot I have enabled

Comment: Solved my issue !
This link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182380/how-to-turn-off-windows-kernel-debugging-at-boot-time